# OS X Mavericks: Git bash prompt has stopped tracking if uncommitted changes are present

Tags: macos, git, bash

I upgraded to 10.9 over the weekend, and my bash prompt display is acting a little funky.  I currently have this in my `.bash_profile`:

```
function parse_git_dirty {
  [[ $(git status 2> /dev/null | tail -n1) != "nothing to commit (working directory clean)" ]] && echo "*"
}
function parse_git_branch {
  git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e "s/* \(.*\)/[\1$(parse_git_dirty)]/"
}

PS1="\n\[\e[1;34m\]\$(date +%H:%M) \[\e[1;36m\]\w\[\e[1;33m\] \$(parse_git_branch) \[\e[1;31m\]\$(rvm_version)\n\[\e[0;32m\]> \[\e[0m\]"
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

That used to (in 10.8) produce a prompt that looked something like this:

```
07:45 ~/code/project_dir [git-branch] 1.9.3@project
```

If there were changes that needed to be committed to my git branch, it would have an asterisk appended (`[git-branch*]`).

Since upgrading, however, it **always** has the `*` listed after the branch. Everything else seems to be functioning like normal.  How can I get it to behave like it did before?

I've updated to the latest version of git as well.

Comment: same question at http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/111762/7057

Comment: Using your code under 10.8.5 I get the `*` all the time as well, so this is not a Mavericks issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @chepner, I switched to using `git-prompt.sh` via homebrew's bash-completion package.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a change in `git` version. When I run `git status` in OS X 10.9 (Git 1.8.3.4), the message from a clean repository is

```
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: There must be a better way of doing it that doesn't rely on that string comparison...

Comment: Probably, but even the `git-prompt.sh` script that ships with `git` parses the text output of `git status` for determining which, if any, files are unstaged and uncommitted (at least, the last time I checked).

Comment: On second look, it seems `git-prompt.sh` has either cleaned up its act, or I was looking at a different script. In any case, the OP should consider using (or at least studying) `contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh` in the Git distribution to find a more robust method for building his prompt.

Comment: +1 This is certainly the root cause of the issue as I am using macports git under 10.8.5 and the OP's scripts don't work with it.

Comment: I can't remember where I grabbed that script from, but I do recall having issues running `git-prompt.sh` under homebrew.  I'll investigate and see if it fixes my issue.